# Conditional Label Color

Tags: jquery, forms, colors

I am having a beast of a time trying to get the label colors to work.   Simply put, depending on a radio button selection, the following form fields are either disabled or enabled.  When they are disabled, I want the labels to grey out.

HTML:

```
<input type="radio" name="Event-Location" value="City2">City 2</input>
<input type="radio" name="Event-Location" value="City1">City 1</input>
<label for="Reservation-Style"> Reservation Style:</label>
<select name="Reservation-Style" id="Reservation-Style">
  <option>- Style -</option>
  <option value="Permits">Individual Permits</option>
  <option value="Cordon">Cordoned Parking Area</option>
</select>
<label  for="Number-Permits-Needed">How Many Permits are needed? </label>
<input id="Number-Permits-Needed" class="text" type="text" name="Number-Permits-Needed" size="15" />
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input:radio[name=Event-Location]').click(function () {
        var checkval = $(this).val();
        $('#Reservation-Style, [for="Reservation-Style"]').prop('disabled', !(checkval == 'City2')).addClass('disabled');
        $('#Reservation-Style, [for="Reservation-Style"]').prop('enabled', !(checkval == 'City1')).removeClass('disabled');
        $('#Number-Permits-Needed, label[for="Number-Permits-Needed"]').prop('disabled', !(checkval == 'City2')).addClass('disabled');
        $('#Number-Permits-Needed, label[for="Number-Permits-Needed"]').prop('enabled', !(checkval == 'City1')).removeClass('disabled');
    });

});
```

And the CS:

```
.disabled {
   color: #666;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your javascript has syntax errors and is causing your problem.  Here is an example for your case where fields are disabled on the change event.  You should be able to extend this for whatever fields you need.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
$('input[name="Event-Location"]').on('change', function () {
    var checkval = $(this).val();
    if (checkval == 'City1') {
        $('label[for="Reservation-Style"]').addClass('disabled');
        $('#Reservation-Style').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
        $('label[for="Number-Permits-Needed"]').addClass('disabled');
        $('#Number-Permits-Needed').prop('disabled', 'disabled');
    } else {
        $('label[for="Reservation-Style"]').removeClass('disabled');
        $('#Reservation-Style').prop('disabled', false);
        $('label[for="Number-Permits-Needed"]').removeClass('disabled');
        $('#Number-Permits-Needed').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
});
```

Fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/faithfulprogrammer/sBpYm/3/